# How to get server-side console app to run on ASP.net website(IIS7)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.net website that is hosted on IIS7, within the asp.net code I have a C# statement that launches a .exe on my webserver on a button click. For some reason in visual studio it will launch on the local development server but when I move it to the IIS7 server it will not pop up a black console box on button click. This is what I am doing.

```
generateSpanish = "/n= " + serverName + "GenerateVoice SpanishVoice";

Process serverSideCommandSpanish = new Process();

serverSideCommandSpanish.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("Config\myexe.exe");
serverSideCommandSpanish.StartInfo.Arguments = generateSpanish;
serverSideCommandSpanish.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
serverSideCommandSpanish.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

serverSideCommandSpanish.Start();
```

Again it launches in visual studio( a black console app pops up on the "server") but on my IIS server it does not do the console app popup serverside?

Comment: Perhaps because your test web server is running as the local user, and IIS is running as a Windows service?

Comment: So you think the .exe is getting executed? just not visible?

Comment: Yea, I don't *think* there's anything preventing you from running an EXE under IIS.  However, it's not going to be able to interact with the shell in any way.  It wouldn't make sense logically, as there might be multiple users logged on, or no users at all logged on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the handler for exe's under IIS7. Do this by going to the web site under MMC and select Handler Mappings.

Comment: This is not the answer.  They are trying to launch an EXE using C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get this to work using telling your Process to run [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) with the -i argument and having PsExec run the .exe you're actually trying to start. The -i argument tells PsExec to execute the target in interactive mode on the desktop of a specified user session.